# Conditional props in React Typescript component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Been battling with this problem for a while now so I turned to Google and now to you since I didn't find anything.

Small background to my problem:
I want to render a table that renders conditional rows based on what type each row is.

This is what I got so far:

```
interface TableRowProps {
  disabled?: boolean
}

type AnimalProps = {
  type: 'animal'
  data?: AnimalData
}

type PersonProps = {
  type: 'person'
  data?: PersonData
}

type ConditionalProps = AnimalProps | PersonProps

const TableRow: FC<TableRowProps & ConditionalProps> = ({ type, data, disabled }) => {
...
```

Naturally I would use this TableRow component in a table to render each row individually. Depending on what state the app is I would choose what type the row would be and also pass the data through iterating through an array

In my code I would use the "type" property to determine what the "data" property holds to render the row accordingly

```
if (type === 'animal') {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{data.animalProp}</td>
    </tr>
  )
}
    
if (type === 'person') {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{data.personProp}</td>
    </tr>
  )
}
```

This is all fine and dandy in VS Code. TypeScript is not complaining with any squiggly red lines or anything like that but at build time in the browser I get:

```
Property 'animalProp' does not exist on type 'PersonType | AnimalType'.
  Property 'animalProp' does not exist on type 'PersonType'.
```

The workaround would be to use "as" to set the types on each occurrence but there has to be a cleaner way out there.

Any help that points me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Best regards,
//G

Answer (score 1):

I think that in your case, type guards could be helpful:

```js
type Person = {
  type: 'person'
}

type Animal = {
  type: 'animal'
}

function isPerson(entity: Person | Animal): entity is Person {
  return (entity as Person).type === 'person';
}
  
const entity: Person | Animal = { type: 'person' }

if (isPerson(entity)) {
  console.log('person')
} else {
  console.log('animal')
}
```

In this case, `person` would get logged in the console. Also note that the proper type would be inferred inside the `if / else` brackets. You can have the detailed explanation in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

Comment: Hey @Mentlegen, thanks for your reply! Yes, this seems to be doing the trick and by the book as well, but I was maybe hoping there would be a slightly cleaner solution. I'm just wondering why TS can't catch my error before build time. Any idea?